# What is the meaning of "I just don't trust you to make it out of here alone."?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In [the] English Fantasy Movie *The Great Wall*, William & Tovar going back to home town from China Dynasty after defeating the beasts. But William last sees the dynasty. Then Tovar asks him like this:

> Tovar: Are you sure you don't want to go back?
>
> William: Of course I do. I just **don't trust you to make it out of here
>   alone**.

Comment: to **make it out of here**  = succeed in escaping from this place;   **dont' trust you to...** = have little faith in your ability to ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @TRomano commented:

- **to make it out of here** means **"to succeed in escaping from this place"**. Like in the example: **"We won't make it out of here alive."**
- **don't trust you to** means **"have little faith in your ability to"**

Answer (score 0):

It means "I don't believe you'll make it out of here on your own, so I'm forced to go with you lest you die."